# How to handle recursion in python?

Tags: python, recursion

Sketched a small function on examples from the Internet, but there were problems with recursion ...

```
def toSimpleXml(data, wrap = False):
    result = list()
    input_data_type = type(data)
    if input_data_type is list:
        for sub_element in data:
            result.append(toSimpleXml(sub_element))
        return ''.join(result)
    elif input_data_type is dict:
        for tag_name in data:
            sub_element = data[tag_name]
            result.append('<%s>' % tag_name)
            result.append(toSimpleXml(sub_element))
            result.append('</%s>' % tag_name)
        return ''.join(result)

    if wrap:
        return '<%s>%s</%s>' % (wrap, data, wrap)

    return data

data = [{'element_1': 'value_1'}, {'element_2': {'element_2_1': 'value_2_1'}}, {'element_1': 'value_1'}]
print toSimpleXml(data, 'root')
```

By the idea result should be wrapped with `root`, but `wrap` variable is false...

Comment: To the close voters: the question is a little vague, but far from lacking sufficient information to diagnose the problem. I was able to spot the problem, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns *too early* for `wrap` to come into play. Set `data` instead of returning:

```
def toSimpleXml(data, wrap = False):
    result = list()
    input_data_type = type(data)
    if input_data_type is list:
        for sub_element in data:
            result.append(toSimpleXml(sub_element))
        data = ''.join(result)
    elif input_data_type is dict:
        for tag_name in data:
            sub_element = data[tag_name]
            result.append('<%s>' % tag_name)
            result.append(toSimpleXml(sub_element))
            result.append('</%s>' % tag_name)
        data = ''.join(result)

    if wrap:
        return '<%s>%s</%s>' % (wrap, data, wrap)

    return data
```

Now the `if wrap` statement is actually reached:

```
>>> print toSimpleXml(data, 'root')
<root><element_1>value_1</element_1><element_2><element_2_1>value_2_1</element_2_1></element_2><element_1>value_1</element_1></root>
```